Date Formatting for SharePoint Event List
I have a requirement where I need to save data to a SharePoint event list using a modal form and display the data as cards on a webpage. However, I'm encountering an issue with date formatting. The dates are not displaying correctly.
I have tried several approaches, including:

Saving the date in UTC format and converting it to local time when displaying.
Using ISO format for date storage and display.

Despite these efforts, the dates are still not showing correctly. Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to resolve this?
Thank you in advance for your help!
$().SPServices(  
    {  
        operation: "UpdateListItems",  
        async: false,  
        webURL: webURL,  
        batchCmd: "New",  
        listName: "Events",  
        valuepairs: [  
            ["Title", Title],
             ["EventDate", EventDate],
             ["EndDate", EndDate],
             ["Location", Location],
             ["Category", Category],
             ["Description", Description]
        ],  
        completefunc: function(xData, Status)  
        {  
            EventId = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").attr("ows_ID");
            if(EventId > 0){
                GetEventData();
            }
        }  
    });


To help you solve the problem better. You'd better explain your problem in more detail (screenshots of errors, desired renderings or values).

which localization and time zone do you use? What are the errors with the date's?

The default time zone in the regional settings is set to (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US and Canada).

And I want the saved date and time to be displayed according to the user's time zone.

okay, but what is the error? The difference between what you get and what you expect?
